# how to use maya created objects in java?

Tags: xml, blender, maya, ogre, jmonkeyengine

We use Blender created objects in 'Jmonkey' XML file by installing 'Ogre Blender XML'.
Is there any process for Maya as it is for Blender??

I didn't find anything for this anywhere

Answer (score 1):

it looks like Jmonkey supports OBJ format, which Maya can export if you have the objexport.mll plugin install.  OBJ is not animatable, however.

http://www.ehow.com/how_6948513_export-_obj-file-autodesk-maya.html